# How can I animated a path with using the rect values?

Tags: swiftui

I want be able to animated this path in code:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var update: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 10.0) {
            
            VStack {
                
                MyShape(value: update)
                    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                    .padding()
                    .animation(.default, value: update)
                
            }
            .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
            .background(Color.gray)
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
            
            
            Button("Update") {
                update.toggle()
            }
            
        }
        .padding(10.0)
        
    }
}
```

I am using animatableData for this reason but animation does not happed. I think I have to translate Bool value to CGFloat or Double but this translation make a new issue of immutable:

> Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable

```
    struct MyShape: Shape {
    
    var value: Bool
    private var dynamicValue: CGFloat = .zero
    
    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { return dynamicValue }
        set(newValue) { dynamicValue = newValue }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        if value {
            dynamicValue = rect.minY
        }
        else {
            dynamicValue = rect.maxY
        }
        
        return Path { path in
            
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: dynamicValue))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX , y: rect.midY))
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing a `Bool` to `MyShape`, pass the `dynamicValue` that can vary from `-1.0` to `1.0`.  That way, the system will be able to provide values between those extremes when animated:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var update: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 10.0) {
            
            VStack {
                
                MyShape(dynamicValue: update)
                    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                    .padding()
                    .animation(.default, value: update)
                
            }
            .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
            .background(Color.gray)
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
            
            
            Button("Update") {
                update = -update
            }
            
        }
        .padding(10.0)
        
    }
}


struct MyShape: Shape {
    
    var dynamicValue: CGFloat
    
    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { return dynamicValue }
        set(newValue) { dynamicValue = newValue }
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        return Path { path in
            
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: dynamicValue * (rect.maxY - rect.minY)/2 + rect.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX , y: rect.midY))
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

---

[image: Demo running in simulator]

Comment: I also end it up using values between 0.0 to 1.0 and also worked for me, you used -1.0 to 1.0 that works as well, the issue is finding the right math formula for such work, with considering that this example was a simple issue, how we can use this method for animating some more advanced path that needs offset or rotation in multi points in same time, cannot imaging how to solve those issues.

Comment: That’s the “art” of it. You need to arrange the math to give you the look you want.  For line segments, you can calculate the endpoints. I would write a function that takes the source and destination points plus the progress 0 to 1 and return the animated coordinate.   You could do the same for a rotation, start and ending angle and progress.